# Trying to compile a list of outputs from a calculator type excel sheet

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a payroll calculator in excel, I have managed to create the calculator to figure out how many hours an employee has worked. Now I want to take that output, and store it into a list on another page and/or area of the current worksheet. Basically, if cell `C1` `=sum(A1, B1)`, I want to plug a number into `A1` and `B1`, get the value in `C1`, but immediately store that value as the first value in a list, starting in `Sheet2!A1`. Then, I want to plug another set of numbers into `A1` and `B1` and get a new value in `C1`, which will now get stored into `Sheet2!A2`.
[The start and end times are drop-down menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxVre.png)
[Here are the formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c4Nf.png)
I want to take that final Hours worked number and store that into a list

Comment: Post some of sample data and expected output. Then show your own effort what you have tried yet.

Comment: Do a verification on sheet2, if the value on sheet.A1 is empty then set sheet2.A1 = C1, else set sheet2.A2 = sheet1.C1...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the whole columns of `A` and `B` rather than `A1` and `B1` only, you can go to `Sheet2` and write the formula

```
=Sheet1!A1+Sheet1!B1
```

then pull it down to cover the whole columns to the number of employees you want, so you can use every row for each employee, `Sheet1!A1`, `Sheet1!B1` and `Sheet2!A1` for the first one, `Sheet1!A2`, `Sheet1!B2` and `Sheet2!A2` for the second one, and so on.